# Using getline consecutively causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, getline

I'm trying to read two consecutive lines of input from stdin using getline. This minimal code causes a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why:

```
int main() {
    char *ln1 = NULL;
    char *ln2 = NULL;
    size_t lnsz1;
    size_t lnsz2;

    getline(&ln1,&lnsz1,stdin);
    getline(&ln2,&lnsz2,stdin);


}
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The char pointers ln1/ln2...I don't have checking for the getline return codes yet @stark

Comment: pointers don't hold data. They point to data

Comment: Err, I suppose whatever getline allocates for the data then?

Comment: @stark From Linux Programmer's Manual regarding `getline`: "ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream); If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
       getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line." So it's fine to have `ln1`and `ln2` as just char pointers. The error must be the missing size initialization.

Comment: If you don't understand *how* it worked, and why the error occurred, then you'll run into the same problem later in a different setting.

Comment: I agree that setting the sizes to zero should fix the problem.  Setting the pointers to null is crucial and should be sufficient.  However, setting the size to zero too removes any last vestige of an excuse from what is, I think, a faulty implementation.  If the values in the uninitialized variables are big enough, the function may be allocating ridiculous amounts of memory and running into trouble because of that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah, seems kind of strange that it isn't sufficent to pass a pointer where *p is NULL but the documentation explicit requires that `*psize` is also zero. Wonder why they did that....

Comment: What OS and C library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194282/using-getline-consecutively-causes-segmentation-fault?noredirect=1#comment113516519_64194282) that setting the size to zero (as well as the pointer to a null pointer) should fix the observed crash.

Lurking in the background is a hypothesis that the specific implementation of `getline()` causing the crash is somewhat faulty.  One possible way in which it could be faulty is if it uses the size argument when allocating space because the pointer is null.  That is somewhat improbable, but the question gives no information on which platform yields the crash.

The POSIX specification of [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) says:

> `ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream);`
>
> …
>
> The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero, the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a null pointer.
>
> If `*lineptr` is a null pointer or if the object pointed to by `*lineptr` is of insufficient size, an object shall be allocated as if by `malloc()` or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`, respectively, such that the object is large enough to hold the characters to be written to it, including the terminating NUL, and `*n` shall be set to the new size. If the object was allocated, or if the reallocation operation moved the object, `*lineptr` shall be updated to point to the new object or new location.
>
> …
>
> Upon successful completion, the `getline()` and `getdelim()` functions shall return the number of bytes written into the buffer, including the delimiter character if one was encountered before EOF, but excluding the terminating NUL character. If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if no characters were read and the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and the function shall return -1. If an error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, and the function shall return -1 and set `errno` to indicate the error.

The code in the question is not self-evidently abusing those rules.  The application ensures that `*lineptr` is a null pointer — which is a value that can be passed to `free()`.  It doesn't much matter what the value of `*n` is because `*lineptr` is a null pointer.

One way to experiment is to try printing the value in the uninitialized variables (`lnsz1` and `lnsz2`), but such experimentation is arguably invoking undefined behaviour.  Another is to initialize the variables to some large values — such as `SIZE_MAX` or `SIZE_MAX / 2` (where `SIZE_MAX` defined in C11 [`<stdint.h>`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.3) but not in earlier versions of the C standard) or other similar inflated values.  You should also test with a value of `0`, of course, and some testing could be done with other small values such as `1`, `8`, `16` etc.  All of these tests would be conducted with the pointers set to a null pointer.  If you can use a memory allocation package such that a debugging version of `malloc()` (or `realloc()`) is called, you may be able to log the requested size of the memory.  You may get some information from printing the value of `lnsz1` after the first call to `getline()` if the crash occurs on the second call.

Such an investigation is barely worth the effort, though.  Setting both the pointers and the sizes to zero should resolve the problem.  If it doesn't, there is more to investigate.  That is, however, unlikely to be the problem.

```c
//#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 // Explicitly request POSIX support
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *ln1 = NULL;
    char *ln2 = NULL;
    size_t lnsz1 = 0;
    size_t lnsz2 = 0;
    ssize_t len1 = -1;
    ssize_t len2 = -1;

    if ((len1 = getline(&ln1, &lnsz1, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        printf("%zd (%zu: %p) [%s]\n", len1, lnsz1, (void *)ln1, ln1);
        if ((len2 = getline(&ln2, &lnsz2, stdin)) != -1)
            printf("%zd (%zu: %p) [%s]\n", len2, lnsz2, (void *)ln2, ln2);
    }
    free(ln1);
    free(ln2);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `getline()` specifically returns `-1` and not `EOF` when it detects an error or end-of-file.  On most systems, the two values are the same, but the [C standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1) only requires that `EOF` is negative — it does not require that it is `-1`.  I cannot determine any circumstance under which a return value of `0` is valid for `getline()`.